# Make an html button appear as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<li id="item2"><button onclick="myFunction2()">About us </button></li>
```

Is there anyway that "About us" can appear as just text and not a button on the website?

Comment: yes now you can use css and modify button property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As like this .

```css
#item2>button{background:none;border:none;outline:none;cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<li id="item2"><button onclick="myFunction2()">About us </button></li>
```

Comment: dear it worked, however when i get the cursor above "About us", It shows as in the snippet code, but not the cursor if as it's capable of being clicked

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the HTML element from `<button>` to `<p>` and it worked while looking same as a regular text.

```
<p onclick="myFunction2()">About us</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
button,button:focus,button:active
{
    border:none;
    background:none;
    outline:none;

}
```

```css
button,
button:focus,
button:active {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<li id="item2">
  <button type="button" onclick="onButtonClick()">About us</button>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this

```
button {
background:none;
border:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

button:focus{
outline: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwtz8735/2/)

Comment: if you used button than this css applicable all button in html so that please used parent class or id if applicable .